# Ошибка : QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *  

import numpy as np
from stl import mesh

from pathlib import Path


        
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 700, 900) 
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        
        self.initUI()
        
        self.currentSTL = None
        self.lastDir = None
        
        self.droppedFilename = None
    
    def initUI(self):
        centerWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centerWidget)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        centerWidget.setLayout(layout)
        
        self.viewer = gl.GLViewWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.viewer, 1)
        
        self.viewer.setWindowTitle('STL Viewer')
        self.viewer.setCameraPosition(distance=40)
        
        g = gl.GLGridItem()
        g.setSize(200, 200)
        g.setSpacing(5, 5)
        self.viewer.addItem(g)

        btn = QPushButton(text="Load STL")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)
        btn.setFont(QFont("Ricty Diminished", 14))
        layout.addWidget(btn)
            
    def showDialog(self):
        directory = Path("")
        if self.lastDir:
            directory = self.lastDir
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", str(directory), "STL (*.stl)")
        if fname[0]:
            self.showSTL(fname[0])
            self.lastDir = Path(fname[0]).parent
            
    def showSTL(self, filename):
        if self.currentSTL:
            self.viewer.removeItem(self.currentSTL)

        points, faces = self.loadSTL(filename)
        meshdata = gl.MeshData(vertexes=points, faces=faces)
        mesh = gl.GLMeshItem(meshdata=meshdata, smooth=True, drawFaces=False, drawEdges=True, edgeColor=(0, 1, 0, 1))
        self.viewer.addItem(mesh)
        
        self.currentSTL = mesh
        
    def loadSTL(self, filename):
        m = mesh.Mesh.from_file(filename)
        shape = m.points.shape
        points = m.points.reshape(-1, 3)
        faces = np.arange(points.shape[0]).reshape(-1, 3)
        return points, faces

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        print("enter")
        mimeData = e.mimeData()
        mimeList = mimeData.formats()
        filename = None
        
        if "text/uri-list" in mimeList:
            filename = mimeData.data("text/uri-list")
            filename = str(filename, encoding="utf-8")
            filename = filename.replace("file:///", "").replace("\r\n", "").replace("%20", " ")
            filename = Path(filename)
            
        if filename.exists() and filename.suffix == ".stl":
            e.accept()
            self.droppedFilename = filename
        else:
            e.ignore()
            self.droppedFilename = None
        
    def dropEvent(self, e):
        if self.droppedFilename:
            self.showSTL(self.droppedFilename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QFileDialog

import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

import numpy as np
from stl import mesh

from pathlib import Path


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 700, 900)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.initUI()

        self.currentSTL = None
        self.lastDir = None

        self.droppedFilename = None

    def initUI(self):
        centerWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centerWidget)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        centerWidget.setLayout(layout)

        self.viewer = gl.GLViewWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.viewer, 1)

        self.viewer.setWindowTitle('STL Viewer')
        self.viewer.setCameraPosition(distance=40)

        g = gl.GLGridItem()
        g.setSize(200, 200)
        g.setSpacing(5, 5)
        self.viewer.addItem(g)

        btn = QPushButton(text="Load STL")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)
        btn.setFont(QFont("Ricty Diminished", 14))
        layout.addWidget(btn)

    def showDialog(self):
        directory = Path("")
        if self.lastDir:
            directory = self.lastDir
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", str(directory), "STL (*.stl)")
        if fname[0]:
            self.showSTL(fname[0])
            self.lastDir = Path(fname[0]).parent

    def showSTL(self, filename):
        if self.currentSTL:
            self.viewer.removeItem(self.currentSTL)

        points, faces = self.loadSTL(filename)
        meshdata = gl.MeshData(vertexes=points, faces=faces)
        mesh = gl.GLMeshItem(meshdata=meshdata, smooth=True, drawFaces=False, drawEdges=True, edgeColor=(0, 1, 0, 1))
        self.viewer.addItem(mesh)

        self.currentSTL = mesh

    def loadSTL(self, filename):
        m = mesh.Mesh.from_file(filename)
        shape = m.points.shape
        points = m.points.reshape(-1, 3)
        faces = np.arange(points.shape[0]).reshape(-1, 3)
        return points, faces

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        print("enter")
        mimeData = e.mimeData()
        mimeList = mimeData.formats()
        filename = None

        if "text/uri-list" in mimeList:
            filename = mimeData.data("text/uri-list")
            filename = str(filename, encoding="utf-8")
            filename = filename.replace("file:///", "").replace("\r\n", "").replace("%20", " ")
            filename = Path(filename)

        if filename.exists() and filename.suffix == ".stl":
            e.accept()
            self.droppedFilename = filename
        else:
            e.ignore()
            self.droppedFilename = None

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        if self.droppedFilename:
            self.showSTL(self.droppedFilename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```